# How to import LaTeX equation into MS Word Equation or into MathType?

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, latex

Say I have this LaTeX code:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
V_{conf}(r) = \frac{A}{r^2} + Br^2 - 2\sqrt{AB}
\end{equation}
```

How to import it in MS Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by using [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) with version >= 6.0.

Comment: Unlike Word's Equation Editor, MathType sucks when exporting to HTML+images.

Answer (score 3):

See here for a list of several solutions, of whom some are free:

[Converters from LaTeX to PC Textprocessors - Overview](http://www.tug.org/utilities/texconv/textopc.html)

Answer (score 2):

http://texpoint.necula.org/

Comment: Thanks, but seems this is not free. Is there a free tool?

Answer (score 1):

There's an open-source converter [here on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latex2rtf/).  I've not used it myself, but the comments look encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're using Windows, but on the off-chance that you are using OS X, my preferred solution is [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php), which creates a picture of the equation that you can drag into Word or elsewhere. A potential Windows analog that I have not tested is [Laeqed](http://www.thrysoee.dk/laeqed/).

[image: LaTeXiT]

[image: Laeqed]

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Aurora (http://elevatorlady.ca/) to good effect in Word and PowerPoint.  It integrates itself into the menu and calls your LaTeX environment (e.g. MikTeX) or its own minimal MikTeX.  The rendered equations can be either bitmaps or vector. For sharing with others, the bitmaps are more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Chrome Extension to convert LaTeX Equations online to Word Equations：https://github.com/idf/LaTex2Word-Equation

[image]